# What sci-fi movie used a tuning fork to open/close the spaceship's doors?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I cannot remember the name of a late 1950's-early '60s sci-fi movie where humans enter an (abandoned?) alien ship and discover that the use of tuning forks open the large circular doors between passageways. The doors (I believe) rolled in and out of place.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this black-and-white?  Was the ship in space or on a planet?  Were the humans wearing space suits, uniforms or normal clothes?

Comment: I recall it being B&W and I believe the ship was on a planet. As far as the humans attire goes...I THINK they were wearing uniforms, but I can't be certain.

Comment: In addition, I should have noted that the tuning forks were already aboard the alien ship. I can't seem to remember the general plot, although (of course) the humans met with some sort of danger...

Answer (score 6):

***[Planet of the Vampires](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059792/)*** (1965)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Vampires):

> *Planet of the Vampires* (Italian: *Terrore nello Spazio*, lit. 'Terror in Space') is a 1965 Italian-Spanish science fiction horror film, produced by Fulvio Lucisano, directed by Mario Bava, that stars Barry Sullivan and Norma Bengell. The screenplay, by Bava, Alberto Bevilacqua, Callisto Cosulich, Antonio Roman and Rafael J. Salvia, was based on an Italian-language science fiction short story, Renato Pestriniero's "One Night of 21 Hours". American International Pictures released the film as the supporting film on a double feature with Daniel Haller's *Die, Monster, Die!* (1965).

From a [review](https://isawafilm.com/2021/05/10/planet-of-the-vampires-1965/):

> The spaceship, a roomy affair with space for dancing, and lots of colored shapes for equipment, goes through a mess of asteroids to land on a planet where another spaceship had already had a mysterious accident. Most of the spaceship shuddering sequences require the actors to kind of lay on each other and look distressed. A sequence of passing through high Gs has them with their heads on their desks. But, soon enough they’re investigating the empty spaceship which was apparently piloted by humungous alien humanoids. A skeleton half buried in the sand is something like 10x human size. **They don’t learn much from the ship except a few moments of accidentally locking themselves into a bridge area and having to use a tuning fork to open the door.**

The protagonists, Captain Markary and Sanya, find themselves trapped within an alien vessel they were exploring. Then around the 52:50 mark, Sanya finds a tuning fork in a small case, and Markary reasons that the opening mechanism for the doors may be triggered by specific frequencies of sound. He isn't able to open the doors with the tuning fork directly, but when he throws it to the floor in frustation, it strikes another object which does end up opening the doors.